# Making calulation with Plain Javascript

Tags: javascript

Since years I am learning with stack overflow, however this is my fist question.
I try to build a price-calculator with java script.

The idea is selecting a license-model (selector), using then a Base-Price (via input field), selecting the user-quantifier (via input field) which has a multiply factor linked. In the end the Base-Price will get multiplied and the final Price will be displayed.


I am quite comfortable that the math part is correct however there must be syntax error I am dismissing. I hope this is a valuable question, since I am getting stuck some time with this.

Would be great if someone has some input on this, thanks.

Here are my thoughts:

```js
// get input from inputfiels
var Licence = parseInt(document.getElementById("Licence").value);
var Quantity = parseInt(document.getElementById("Quantity").value);
var Basis = parseInt(document.getElementById("Basis").value);

// Desktop User numbers
var User = [3, 8, 16, 36, 50];

// Web View numbers
var View = [20, 50, 80, 200, 500];

// linked multiply factor (eg. 16 users = multiply factor x 3, or 50 views = multiply factor x 2)
var Multiply = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

// Calcutation Desktop
function Desktop_Kernel(Quantity, Basis) {
  var index;
  for (index of Multiply) {
    if (User[index - 1] == Quantity) {
      return Basis * Multiply[index - 1];
    }
  }
}

// Calcutation Web
function Web_Kernel(Quantity, Basis) {
  var index;
  for (index of Multiply) {
    if (View[index - 1] == Quantity) {
      return Basis * Multiply[index - 1];
    }
  }
}

// Licece Model: Desktop or Web
function Licence_Selector() {
  if (Licence == 1) {
    var Price = Desktop_Kernel(Quantity, Basis);
  } else if (Licence == 2) {
    var Price = Web_Kernel(Quantity, Basis);
  }

  document.getElementById("Price").value = Price;
}
// show output
document.getElementById("Price").value = Desktop_Kernel(Quantity, Basis);
```

```html
<select id="Licence">
  <option value="1">Desktop</option>
  <option value="2">Web</option>
</select>

<input type="number" id="Basis" placeholder="Basis Price" >
<input type="number" id="Quantity" placeholder="Quantity">

<input type="button" value="Display Price" onclick="Licence_Selector()">
<input type="text" id="Price">
```

Comment: First job would be to properly indent your code. Helps you to maintain it, and helps us to read and understand your issue.

Comment: @Utkanos I took the liberty of reformatting OP's code with Prettier, so that's no longer an issue.

Comment: You should not read the input values on page load, but when the click event is handled.

Comment: I would suggest building a more combined data structure, having three separate arrays that have to maintain the same order is generally going to cause you problems later. You could have a single array of objects with three properties.

Comment: You have declared and assigned value to `Licence` and others at global level. Since it will calculated when script is loaded and then it won't get updated. So you will get always `Licence = ''`. Use `parseInt(document.getElementById("Licence").value)` wherever you have used `Licence`, similar with other `variables` also.

Comment: Also, when in your functions the `if` condition is never true, that function will return `undefined`. Your code should probably determine in those cases how else the result should be calculated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You need to read the inputs within your calculation function.
- There's no need to have two kernel functions that only change one variable; instead pass that list in as an argument.
- I'm not sure your calculations are correct; if Quantity is not listed within the User/View arrays, then it will always return `undefined`. Should that maybe be `>=` instead of `==`, to have a tier system? (I corrected it as such, not sure if that's what you meant.)

```js
// Desktop User numbers
var User = [3, 8, 16, 36, 50];

// Web View numbers
var View = [20, 50, 80, 200, 500];

// linked multiply factor (eg. 16 users = multiply factor x 3, or 50 views = multiply factor x 2)
var Multiply = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

function Kernel(Numbers, Quantity, Basis) {
  var index;
  for (index of Multiply) {
    if (Numbers[index - 1] >= Quantity) {
      return Basis * Multiply[index - 1];
    }
  }
}

// Licece Model: Desktop or Web
function Recalculate() {
  // get input from inputfields
  var Licence = parseInt(document.getElementById("Licence").value);
  var Quantity = parseInt(document.getElementById("Quantity").value);
  var Basis = parseInt(document.getElementById("Basis").value);
  var Numbers = (Licence == 1 ? User : View);
  var Price = Kernel(Numbers, Quantity, Basis);
  document.getElementById("Price").value = Price;
}
```

```html
<select id="Licence" value="1">
  <option value="1">Desktop</option>
  <option value="2">Web</option>
</select>

<input type="number" id="Basis" placeholder="Basis Price" >
<input type="number" id="Quantity" placeholder="Quantity">

<input type="button" value="Display Price" onclick="Recalculate()">
<input type="text" id="Price">
```

Comment: Shouldn't Quantity be taken into account in the Kernel function ?